# What is the smallest possible hoik

Tags: terraria

I am trying to make an engine with a hoik loop. I know how to make a hoik loop, but cannot seem to work out how to meet the smallest one possible. I need to know the smallest possible hoik loop

---

## What is a hoik

The hoik was originally a glitch in which one would glitch/actuate them self into a line of sloped tiles which would continually displace them. Now, it is an official feature.

Click [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JeysbJAFIa0) for a video on it.

---

## What is a hoik loop?

The hoik loop is hoiks string together in such a way that they make a continuous rectangular loop.

Click [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R8-4B4s2Nco) for a video on it.

---

[Wiki Page](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Hoik)

Comment: I think this question was downvoted because it doesn't explain what a hoik is. You could argue it's a term common in the game, but I like to think of myself as "knowledgeable" in Terraria, and I have never heard of hoiks. I've found a post on the official forums that explains the mechanics and shows a lot of examples [here](https://forums.terraria.org/index.php?threads/hoik-guide-rapid-player-npc-etc-transport-using-only-sloped-tiles.1656/).

Comment: Yes, but that page does not show the necessary information. Also, I am directing my question to the more technical terrarians

Comment: Hi brododragon, welcome to Arqade! As Ivo rightfully pointed out, it might be a good idea to edit your question to include context about what a hoik is. Speaking anecdotally, I have over 500 hours in Terraria and have never heard of hoik loops.

Comment: okay I guess I'll edit then

Comment: I find this interesting, as I had thought that hoiks were common knowledge to more experienced players, but it seems as though they’re more of a niche mechanic than I expected. Also, I’m fairly certain the answer to your question is 3x4(for players), but I’m not certain. I know for items it’s simply a 2x2 square.

Comment: Okay I’ll play around